# ASP.NET authorisation allow "*" vs "?"

Tags: asp.net, authorization

If I set an all-users authorization rule e.g. `<allow users="*"/>` does this also allow anonymous users (ie. ones that haven't logged in) to see the resource?

How about vice-versa - if I allow anonymous users with "?" can all logged in users also see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - * means absolutely anybody
2. Yes - ? means anonymous users from which all users "inherit"

Comment: do you have a link to the docs somewhere where this is described? the authorization page itself doesn't specify the difference.